# Spring security method level permission not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

I've been trying out 'Method Level' security on my application and I cant get it working.
I have my spring-security file looking like this :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


     <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"  secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <beans:import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/test*"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            default-target-url="/test" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />

        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout"
            logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>



    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                role-prefix="ROLE_"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, true as enabled FROM USER WHERE username=?;"
                authorities-by-username-query="select
    u.username,
    r.name
    from
    user u,
    role r,
    user_role ur
    where 
    u.ID = ur.USER_ID and 
    r.id = ur.ROLE_ID 
    and 
    u.id in ( 
    SELECT id FROM USER WHERE username=? 
    );" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

my servlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvchttp://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"> 
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />   

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="hr.juka.app" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jukadb"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="username" value="root"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="password" value=""/> -->
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userRepositoryImpl" class="hr.juka.app.dao.UserRepository">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
</bean>


<bean id="loginBusinessImpl" class="hr.juka.app.business.LoginBusiness">
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

my web.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my controller :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    private LoginBusiness loginBusiness;

    ...


    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test() {
        User user = loginBusiness.getLoggedUser();
        String name = user.getUsername(); //get logged in username

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test");
        model.addObject("name", name);


        return model;
    }

}
```

my business interface ILoginBusiness :

```
public interface ILoginBusiness {

    User getLoggedUser();

}
```

my business class LoginBusiness :

```
public class LoginBusiness implements ILoginBusiness {

@Override
public User getLoggedUser() {

    User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    return user;
}}
```

If I leave my code like above, everything works fine but without method security because I didnt put my annotations yet, but when I add `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")` in my interfice like this :

```
public interface ILoginBusiness {

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    User getLoggedUser();

}
```

then i get this error :

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private hr.juka.app.business.LoginBusiness hr.juka.app.controller.LoginController.loginBusiness; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set hr.juka.app.business.LoginBusiness field hr.juka.app.controller.LoginController.loginBusiness to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1777)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private hr.juka.app.business.LoginBusiness hr.juka.app.controller.LoginController.loginBusiness; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set hr.juka.app.business.LoginBusiness field hr.juka.app.controller.LoginController.loginBusiness to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set hr.juka.app.business.LoginBusiness field hr.juka.app.controller.LoginController.loginBusiness to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
```

my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMvcHibernateXML</artifactId>
    <name>SpringMvcHibernateXML</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Database Connection Pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${spring.security.version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the same if I put `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` annotation.
If I put it in my controller than I dont get error but method security is not working, it allow user with role ROLE_USER to access my method. 
I tried a lot of combination and cant figure how to solve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should be programming to interfaces not concrete classes. Inject `ILoginBusiness` instead of `LoginBusiness` into your controller (that is the whole point of an interface in the first place!

Comment: For `@PreAuthorize` to work on your controllers add the `global-method-security` in your `servlet-context.xml` as well.

Comment: If i declare my interface :  
<bean id="loginBusiness" class="hr.juka.app.business.api.ILoginBusiness">
 </bean>
and in controller i autowire interface, than i get 

Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ...

Comment: Read, please read... I only mentioned the change in your controller NOT your bean definitions...

Comment: Unrelated but dangerous you are mixing jars of different Spring versions and Spring Security versions never do that. (Spring AOP is using the Spring Security version instead of the Spring Version and your `spring-security-aspects` is using a fixed version instead of `${spring.security.version}`.

Comment: Also unrelated but dangerous is the fact that you are mixing hibernate4 and hibernate3 classes in your xml configuration (your `LocalSessionFactorybean` is from hibernate4, the `HibernateTemplate` from hibernate3... And even maybe worse you are loading the `servlet-context.xml` twice, duplicating all the beans!!! So this might even lead to the fact that you think you have secured things while you really haven't.

Comment: if I add @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") in interface and @Autowired
 private ILoginBusiness loginBusiness; in my controller, it still doesnt work and allows ROLE_USER to access

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to do all the thing you mention and see if it helps

Comment: That is because you are loading your configuration twice. Also you should place the interface on the implementation not the interface!>

Comment: i imported <beans:import resource="servlet-context.xml" /> in spring-security.xml because otherwise I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException because I cant get my dataSource in authentication-provider : <authentication-provider>
   <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"...

Comment: i'll try to play around with this problem. thank you for your directions.

Comment: Which makes every bean duplicated and leading to weird to debug issues, like this one. The servlet-context should only contain web related beans (controllers, view resolvers etc.) whereas the root context (which includes the security context) should contain services, repositories, datasources, entityamangers etc.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I moved all the beans in separate file (services.xml) and imported it in spring-security instead of servlet-context.xml as i did before and i added my services file to contextConfigLocation in my web.xml. Now it works as it should. Thank you so much!